# light LED panel symbole meaning

Tags: led, driver, light

Please if anyone know what does mean this symbole. [image]

Comment: Looks like 'no rainbow-sized springs when there's a train coming'...

Comment: The friendly manual is likely to have many pages about things you shouldn't do with the product, explaining this weird barb wire symbol.

Comment: And unfortunately this is probably a symbol from some ISO standard... There's a lot of incredibly bad standards for international symbols.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think this symbol is that bad. That is a very common way of drawing insulation in building drawings etc.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny I wouldn't know about that, but I suppose "don't place insulation in the roof above this light" could be a sensible interpretation. Maybe this question shouldn't be asked here but at a construction (web) site?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

To me it seems to imply that the upper part of the LED fixture (when mounted in a ceiling) should not be covered with cavity insulating material i.e. it needs to keep cool by using circulatory air in the ceiling cavity. After all, it is a 24 watt device and it will need to be kept cool.

---

User Klas-kenny found [this link](http://www.ledbenchmark.com/faq/LED-standards.html#:%7E:text=marked%20carrying%20the%20%27-,Do%20Not%20Cover,-%27%20IEC%20symbol%2C%20pictured) that appears to confirm my suspicion: -

[image]

Comment: This is indeed correct. Very common on LED lights, described here, for example: http://www.ledbenchmark.com/faq/LED-standards.html#:~:text=marked%20carrying%20the%20%27-,Do%20Not%20Cover,-%27%20IEC%20symbol%2C%20pictured I'm pretty sure this symbol is defined by IEC or similar, although I cannot find which standard.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny good find; I shall add that to my answer.

Comment: I would have figured no reflector housings. But for the same reason, don't want to cook the modules.